# How to know the bounding rect of rotated item

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Say, I have a `Flickable` with an `Image` somewhere inside. I need to update `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` accordingly. While it is possible to make appropriate calculations manually, I wonder if there is a way to get the bounding rectangle of the `Image` (as well as any other `Item`)?

**EDIT** (in response to [Mitch's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442990/how-to-know-the-bounding-rect-of-rotated-item/26443285#26443285)):

At first glance it looked like awesome example. I even started to think that I have missed something while trying to use `Item.childrenRect` group of properties... Unfortunately, having modified the provided example so that boundary is drawn right around the children items, I have convinced myself again that the `childrenRect`'s properties do not respect rotation of the items. See below:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Component.onCompleted: addChildItem()

    function addChildItem() {
        var rect = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {}", container);
        rect.x = Math.random() * 200;
        rect.y = Math.random() * 200;
        rect.width = 64 * slider.value;
        rect.height = 64 * slider.value;
        rect.color = "green";
        rect.opacity = 0.5;
        rect.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
    }

    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Slider {
            id: slider
            value: 0.5

            Text {
                text: "Child item size"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.bottom: parent.top
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Add child item"
            onClicked: addChildItem()
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: container
        x: 50
        y: 50
    }

    Item {
        x: container.x
        y: container.y
        Rectangle {
            x: container.childrenRect.x
            y: container.childrenRect.y
            width: container.childrenRect.width
            height: container.childrenRect.height
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounding rectangle can be calculated by a custom function. Below is QML code that does and illustrates exactly that. Code below only accounts for rotation, however could be tweaked to also account for translation and scale. Knowing bounding rectangle of single transformed item, one can iterate over bounding rectangles of multiple items and calculate overall bounding rectangle.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    function rotatePoint(point, pivotPoint, degrees) {
        var radians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
        var sinAngle = Math.sin(radians)
        var cosAngle = Math.cos(radians)

        var pointX = point.x
        var pointY = point.y

        var pivotPointX = pivotPoint.x
        var pivotPointY = pivotPoint.y

        pointX -= pivotPointX
        pointY -= pivotPointY

        var rotatedPointX = (pointX * cosAngle - pointY * sinAngle) + pivotPointX
        var rotatedPointY = (pointX * sinAngle + pointY * cosAngle) + pivotPointY

        return Qt.point(rotatedPointX, rotatedPointY)
    }

    function calculateBoundingRect(rect, degrees) {
        var x = rect.x
        var y = rect.y
        var width = rect.width
        var height = rect.height

        var centerPoint = Qt.point(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)

        var topLeftPoint = Qt.point(x, y)
        var topRightPoint = Qt.point(x + width, y)
        var bottomRightPoint = Qt.point(x + width, y + height)
        var bottomLeftPoint = Qt.point(x, y + height)

        var rotatedTopLeftPoint = rotatePoint(topLeftPoint, centerPoint, degrees)
        var rotatedTopRightPoint = rotatePoint(topRightPoint, centerPoint, degrees)
        var rotatedBottomRightPoint = rotatePoint(bottomRightPoint, centerPoint, degrees)
        var rotatedBottomLeftPoint = rotatePoint(bottomLeftPoint, centerPoint, degrees)

        var rotatedPointsXValues = [rotatedTopLeftPoint.x, rotatedTopRightPoint.x, rotatedBottomRightPoint.x, rotatedBottomLeftPoint.x]
        var rotatedPointsYValues = [rotatedTopLeftPoint.y, rotatedTopRightPoint.y, rotatedBottomRightPoint.y, rotatedBottomLeftPoint.y]

        var rotatedPointsMinX = Math.min.apply(null, rotatedPointsXValues)
        var rotatedPointsMaxX = Math.max.apply(null, rotatedPointsXValues)
        var rotatedPointsMinY = Math.min.apply(null, rotatedPointsYValues)
        var rotatedPointsMaxY = Math.max.apply(null, rotatedPointsYValues)

        var boundingRectTopLeftPoint = Qt.point(rotatedPointsMinX, rotatedPointsMinY)
        var boundingRectTopRightPoint = Qt.point(rotatedPointsMaxX, rotatedPointsMinY)
        var boundingRectBottomLeftPoint = Qt.point(rotatedPointsMinX, rotatedPointsMaxY)

        return Qt.rect(
                    boundingRectTopLeftPoint.x, boundingRectTopLeftPoint.y,
                    boundingRectTopRightPoint.x - boundingRectTopLeftPoint.x,
                    boundingRectBottomLeftPoint.y - boundingRectTopLeftPoint.y)
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        width: 100
        height: 200
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop {
                position: 0
                color: "#1ce327"
            }

            GradientStop {
                position: 1
                color: "#0e65ec"
            }
        }
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        antialiasing: true
        rotation: slider.value

        property rect boundingRect: calculateBoundingRect(Qt.rect(x, y, width, height), rotation)
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        width: rectangle1.boundingRect.width
        height: rectangle1.boundingRect.height
        color: "#00000000"
        antialiasing: true
        border.width: 1
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
        antialiasing: true

        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10

        from: -720
        to: 720
        value: 0
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`childrenRect` should give you the bounding rect with rotation taken into account, but there's a bug: [childrenRect doesn't take transformations into account.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38953)

---

**Original answer:**

Use [childrenRect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childrenRect-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Component.onCompleted: addChildItem()

    function addChildItem() {
        var rect = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.3; Rectangle {}", container);
        rect.x = Math.random() * 100;
        rect.y = Math.random() * 100;
        rect.width = 64 * slider.value;
        rect.height = 64 * slider.value;
        rect.color = "green";
        rect.opacity = 0.5;
        rect.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
    }

    Row {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Slider {
            id: slider
            value: 0.5

            Text {
                text: "Child item size"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.bottom: parent.top
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Add child item"
            onClicked: addChildItem()
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Text {
        text: "Total rotated bounds"

        Rectangle {
            id: boundsRect
            width: container.childrenRect.width
            height: container.childrenRect.height
            anchors.top: parent.bottom
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I need. See edit of my initial post.

Comment: Right... I vaguely remember this now; there's a bug with childrenRect. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Voted for bug report. Will be waiting it to be squashed. I accept your answer in advance so that this question & answer pair may become relevant in future.